# C# Rich Text Box Tags

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a richtext box which will load text from a server. From the server side I want add formatting tags which will be generated textbox. 
For example:

```
result = result.Replace("[b]", @"{\b ").Replace("[/b]", "}").Replace("[br]", @"{\line}").Replace("[i]", @"{\i ").Replace("[/i]", "}");
TextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi " + result + "}";
```

I can then enter:

```
Hello [b]this is in bold[/b] and [i] this is in [/i]
```

which will thus be replaced the required rtf1\ansi formatting and displayed with the required text in bold and italic accordingly.

I would like to implement underline and perhaps even a set of colours.

I've tried `{\u underlin }` but that didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the simple example I created. Attach the whole text to your RTF property.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green128\blue0;}
This is \cf1 \ulwave\ulc2 underlined \ulnone\cf0 text \par
}
```

I could not find very good references that directly work with the RTF property but there are a lot of examples that first performed a selection and then applied the needed properties. I tried out a few of those examples and then checked the RTF text generated. This is a easy way to understand how the Richtextbox works with RTF strings. Hoping this small tip helps you too :) .

Note that on line 2, I have placed a color table with 2 colors i.e. 2 RGB values separated by semicolons. You can add your desired colors here and refer to them as 1,2, etc. I believe that 0 is the default color and is white.

Comment: how will this be implemented so that it'll replace my [u] and [/u] tags with something similar to the {\b and } tags?
My question is less about formatting in RichTextBoxes but more about the tags on offer such as {\b and }